# Can't access the mod dashboard without the mouse

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, accessibility

While I can open up the mod inbox by pressing <kbd>Q</kbd>, I can't access `/admin`, which is linked at the top of that dropdown.

[image: image of dashboard link]

While I can use the number keys to get to each item in the dropdown, <kbd>tab</kbd> moves the focus from the diamond inbox directly to the link to your profile, not allowing me to get to the "dashboard" link, which isn't an item in the dropdown.

<sub>If you're confused as to why it's important that things be accessible without the mouse, please read up on [keyboard accessibility](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/). While I thankfully don't have any physical problems with using 
a mouse, I'm using my time with a broken mouse to give accessibility feedback so that people who need it can get a better site experience.</sub>